# Perl CGI Script backticks with root

Tags: perl, cgi, backticks

I wanted to run a Perl CGI script with backticks.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use warnings;
use strict;

use JSON;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp 'fatalsToBrowser';

my $cgi = CGI->new;  

my $result = `lpc status all`;
print $cgi->header(-type => "plain/text", -charset => "utf-8"); 
print $result;
```

The script runs without issue but returns an empty string.
When I use a command like `ls` it works perfectly.
My guess is that in this case the lpc command I need elevated privileges because when i just run the script from the bash as root it works fine.

**The Question:**
Is there a way to run such a script with backticks over Apache? Is there a Perl module that can help me achieve it otherwise?

The only solution that came to my mind would be to write a service programm that listens to TCP ports themselves but I didn't want to go down that route.

**NEW TRY:**
I have also tried making a bash script with the following content

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo lpc status all
```

I edited /etc/sudoers to this

```
apache   ALL=(ALL)   NOPASSWD:/path/to/script/lpcsa.sh
```

and changed the perl script as followed

```
my  $result = qx(bash lpcsa.sh);
```

out of the command line it works now but over HTTP it just does not want to :/

Comment: Your content type is wrong. It should be `text/plain` (that's not causing your problem, I just thought you should know).

Comment: "returns an empty string" doesn't mean "without issue". Some other things to try are to capture the stderr of the command (`$result = qx(lpc status all 2>&1)`) and to output the exit status (`$?`).

Comment: ah damn ..  in my original it is correct .. the latest one is my test case with IPC::System::Simple module and i wrote this snippet from memory and turned that around :)  -----------

the suggestion with STDERR to STDOUT still returns an empty string and $? returns "0"

Comment: Does the shell script work without the sudo? If not, why do you expect the perl script executing a command to work without? If it does, why are you using sudo? This seems like a permission issue to me.

Comment: yes it works without sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to remember that the web server is running your program not you. When you run ls or lpc it works because you have /bin and /usr/sbin in your PATH. Run: which lpc ... when I do I get /usr/sbin/lpc which means that I need /usr/sbin in my PATH in order to run lpc without giving full path. Try adding the line:

```
print "\nPATH=" . $ENV{'PATH'};
```

to the end of your program. If the required directory is not present, one thing you could do is add:

```
$ENV{'PATH'} .= ":/usr/sbin";
```

or some such to your program before any system or back-tick calls

Comment: you are actually totally correct .. i found that little tidbid out aswell and commands like lpc status all will work like this ---- commands like "service lpd restart" that actually need root access are still problematic but my solution for that is to have a small perl deamon running that waits on a socket